# Modify Config Option for an Individual Slide

Tags: reveal.js

I wanted all of my reveal.js slides [to start at the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22446161/can-i-align-reveal-js-slides-to-the-top-of-the-page), so I modified the `center` option in the config to `false`. However, I'd like a particular slide to have that configuration re-enabled. Is there something I can add to the `<section>` brackets to modify this? Something like this (which doesn't work):

```
<section id="questions" data-markdown data-center="true">
        <script type="text/template">
            #Questions?
        </script>
</section>
```

Similar to the question of [Hide slide number on title page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31146251/hide-slide-number-on-title-page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with [`data-state`](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#slide-states):

```
<section data-state="centerText" data-markdown>
    # Questions?
</section>
```

Then at the end of the `<script>` (after `Reveal.initialize()`) add the following:

```
Reveal.addEventListener( 'centerText', function() {
    Reveal.configure({center: true});
}, false );
```

This will center the text only in those slides with `data-state="centerText"`.

Comment: Great solution! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: This appears to center all slides (Firefox 48.0.1) rather than just one.

Comment: Works in FF 59, but doesn't work on the first slide (have to navigate forward and than back to slide #1 to take effect). I use the `ready` event for the first slide now